# Posting with AFNetworking, parameters not being sent?

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

Here's my Objective-C code:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"fname", @"fname",
                            @"age", @"age",
                            nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"testpost.php" parameters:params];
```

Here's my code in PHP:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br />
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.
```

However, when I get the response back in Obj-C, all I see is:

success: 
*Welcome !

You are  years old.*

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: The code sample only goes so far as to create the `NSURLRequest` object, and doesn't show the code for creating and starting the operation (e.g. using `AFHTTPClient -HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure` and `AFHTTPClient -enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:`. Could you please add that to your original question?

Answer (score 2):

My bet is that you tried to simplify your question and your real code looks something like this:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"id", @"id",
                           nil, @"bla",
                           @"fname", @"fname",
                           @"age", @"age",
                           nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"testpost.php" parameters:params];
```

If you have assigned a nil value to a key like this in your dictionary (probably not purposely), your server will only be able to read the parameters before that value - in my example only the id. So check for nil values in your params dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem appears to be that you really should be using actual values (or objects) for those keys?

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            yourNameObjectAsNSString, @"fname",
                            yourAgeObjectAsNSNumber, @"age",
                            nil];
```

This doesn't explain why you are seeing nothing for the `fname` variable on the PHP side (I would expect it would be `fname` as well, since that's the string that you have it set to in your current `NSDictionary` object), but this might help you get closer to the finish line.